# Make Tablix Column group show when filter returns no rows - SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am working on some SSRS reports and am running into an issue where Tablix Column groups drop from the table when the filter returns no rows.

Is there any way to make this column appear but with empty cells? I have another tablix grouping adjacent with the same columns and I want the columns to all line up on the multiple tablix.

Am I just missing a simple option?

Comment: "when the filter returns no rows" - is this a filter on the tablix in SSRS, or a condition in your datasource (eg. in your SQL query)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe add a

> UNION SELECT '', n ..., '';

clause to your report query? It's ugly but should work. If you go this route, add a comment for your colleagues (or your future self) that will have to maintain the report.

Answer (score 0):

I have not been able to make these columns appear on the SSRS report end.  Specifically I am getting data by month for display.  My solution is make a "Result" table on the SQL side with $0 for every combination, then update this table.
Frustrating, but it works.